# An operation to guarantee a set contains distinct values

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, combinations

Suppose we have a set $A = \{a_0,a_1, \ldots,a_K\}$ consists of a sequence of nonnegative real numbers where $a_k \neq a_{j}$ for all $k,j$ with $a_k=2\pi k/M$. Let $B = \{b_0,b_1, \ldots, b_N\}$ is a set of nonnegative real numbers. Is there any way to obtain $B^\prime = \{b_0^\prime,b_1^\prime, \ldots, b_N^\prime\}$ by an operation/mapping on the set $B$ such that guarantees $C \triangleq \{c_0, c_1, \ldots, c_{NK}\}$, where $c_q = a_k + b_\ell^\prime$, contains distinct elements? One can consider $b_\ell^\prime = f(b_\ell)$ for all $\ell$ where $f$ maps every element $b_\ell \in B$ to $b_\ell^\prime \in B^\prime$.

Comment: As $C$ contains $A$, and $A$ contains $a_0=0$, $a_1=2\pi/M$, $a_2=4\pi/M$ and $a_3=6\pi/M$, and $a_0+a_3=a_1+a_2$, you're not going to get a Sidon set for $K\ge3$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and revised the question.

Comment: What is meant by "an operation on the set $B$"? Does deleting all the elements of $B$ count as an operation on $B$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Not actually. That could be a mathematical operation on $b_{\ell}$s.

Comment: Any operation on $B$ is an operation on the $b_i$, isn't it? But at any rate telling me that deleting all the elements of $B$ doesn't count as an operation on $B$ doesn't tell me what *is* an operation on $B$.

Comment: $B^\prime$ must be a meaningful set with $N$ components obtained by the elements of $B$.

Comment: I take it by "components" you mean "elements". I don't know what a "meaningful" set is. And "obained by the elements of $B$" is far too vague for there to be an answer. I'm afraid you have to think long and hard about what it is you really want to ask, and then express yourself in a mathematically meaningful, precise, unambiguous way.

Comment: Let $b_{\ell}'=2\pi(k\ell+1)/M$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks for your response. However, the desired $b_{\ell}^\prime$ should be based on $b_{\ell}$ not only $\ell$.

Comment: Good. It has taken two days and six inquiries to get you to clarify your question – I think you shouold edit the question so users can see what you're asking without trawling through all these comments.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be a basis, containing $1$, for the reals as a vector space over the rationals. Then $S$ is uncountable and, replacing an element $s$ by $-s$ if necessary, we may assume all the elements of $S$ are nonnegative; further, if $s,t$ are distinct elements of $S$ then $s-t$ is irrational.

Now let $f$ be a bijection from the nonnegative reals to $S$. Then all the numbers $a_k+f(b_{\ell})$ are distinct. For if $a_k+f(b_{\ell})=a_j+f(b_m)$ then $f(b_{\ell})-f(b_m)=a_j-a_k$ is rational, but $f(b_{\ell}),f(b_m)$ are both in $S$ so we must have $f(b_{\ell})=f(b_m)$, so $a_j=a_k$ and $j=k$, but also $f$ is one-one so $b_{\ell}=b_m$, so $\ell=m$, and we're done.

EDIT to give more details on first paragraph:

The rationals are a field. The reals are a vector space over this field. Every vector space has a basis (this requires the Axiom of Choice). Any finite set of linearly independent vectors can be extended to a basis. $\{\,1\,\}$ is a linearly independent set (indeed, any one-element set in a vector space is a linearly independent set, provided the one element is not the zero element). So the reals have a basis which contains $1$.

If a basis contains a negative number $s$, then you still have a basis if you replace $s$ with $-s$, since any linear combination $as+\sum a_is_i$ involving $s$ is equivalent to a linear combination $(-a)(-s)+\sum a_is_i$ involving $-s$ instead. So we may assume we have a basis $S$ for the reals as a vector space over the rationals, that $S$ contains $1$, and that all the elements of $S$ are positive.

Further, suppose $s,t$ are distinct elements of our basis $S$, and suppose $s-t=u$ is rational. Then $0=s-t-u=(1)s+(-1)t+(-u)1$ is a linear combination of the basis elements $s,t,1$ with rational coefficients $1,-1,-u$, but by definition of a basis $s,t,1$ are linearly independent over the rationals, so we have reached a contradiction. Hence if $s,t$ are distinct elements of $S$ then $s-t$ is irrational.

Here endeth extra details on first paragraph.

EDIT to give a more constructive solution:

Write $[x]$ for the integer part of the real number $x$, and $\{x\}$ for the fractional part of $x$ (so $[x]$ is an integer, $0\le\{x\}<1$, and $x=[x]+\{x\}$).

Let $f(x)=[x]+(2M)^{-1}\{x\}$. Then $f$ is a one-one function from the nonnegative reals to the nonnegative reals. If $a_k+f(b_{\ell})=a_j+f(b_m)$ then $f(b_{\ell})-f(b_m)=a_j-a_k$. Now the right side is either zero or a multiple of $2\pi/M$, while the distance from the left side to the nearest integer is at most $1/M$, so for the equation to hold, both sides must be zero (I'm assuming $M$ is large enough that $2\pi K/M<1$, but with a little fiddling we can remove that restriction). Thus, $a_j=a_k$, so $j=k$, and $f(b_{\ell})=f(b_m)$, so $b_{\ell}=b_m$, so $\ell=m$, and we're done.

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer?

Comment: I really, really wish you would stop moving the goalposts.